# Nedarim 61 and multiple year neder

Tags: nedarim-shevuot, tractate-nedarim, leap-years

I'm a gentile and have studied Nedarim 61 a little bit recently. From what I've gathered so far, when someone makes a neder for "this year" or "a year", it means for the rest of the year, whether that year ends up being a leap year or not. But if he makes it for "one year" it means 12 months from the day he made that neder.

If I'm correct on this, what would be the time period if he made the neder for "two years" or "10 years"? How would the time period be determined?

Comment: IIRC it would be to end the day before the same date it was made (on the calendar) in the year it is scheduled to end. This is from memory only so I do not have a source. I would have to search through the Rambam on nedarim for the exact citation.